# ¿operador de desplazamiento >> y <<?

Tags: c++, c

hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto y en un repositorio de GitHub aparece la siguiente función
y no la entiendo debido a que aparece este operador << y >> y no lo entiendo es como un operador de desplazamiento según lo que he leído ,no se si puedan poner un ejemplo para que pueda comprenderlo mejor

```
uint32_t rand_next(void) //period 2^96-1
{
    uint32_t t = x;
    t ^= t << 11;
    t ^= t >> 8;
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    w ^= w >> 19;
    w ^= t;
    return w;
}
```

Comment: operadores bitwise, comunmente llamadas operaciones bits a bits. Realizan el desplazamiento en los bits de un número

Comment: [Un ejemplo](http://ocw.uc3m.es/cursos-archivados/arquitectura-de-ordenadores/lecturas/html/images/isa/shift.png).

Comment: `0b00000001 << 1 == 0b00000010`. El número se recorrió 1 bit a la izquierda
`0b00000001 << 3 == 0b00001000`. El número se recorrió 3 bit a la izquierda
`0b00010001 >> 1 == 0b00001000`. El número se recorrió 1 bit a la derecha
`0b00010001 >> 6 == 0b00000000`. El número se recorrió 6 bit a la derecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador << desplaza todos los bits a la izquierda rellenando con cero en la derecha es el equivalente a multiplicar por 2 el desplazamiento a la derecha >> desplaza los bits a la derecha equivalente a dividir entre dos (estas operaciones a nivel de bits son más rápidas).
Nota:  La variable te indica uint32_t que tiene 32 bits de longitud es decir 4 bytes.

Ejemplo:

```
     uint8_t mask = 0x01;
```

Esto es equivalente a 0000 0001 cuando desplazas a la izquierda es decir:

```
     mask = mask << 1;
```

Te quedaría 0000 0010 que en hexadecimal sería 0x02 , como sabes cada bit son potencias de dos por eso al desplazarse a la izquierda multiplicad.

En ese caso usan un XOR tambien:

```
    t ^= t  << 13
```

Esto es equivalente a:

```
    t = t ^ (t  << 13);
```

Suponiendo que t = 0x00000011 que sería 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 aplicando la operación de arriba sería algo como esto:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000  0000 0000  0001 0001 ^ ( 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 << 13)
```

La operación con el desplazamiento a la izquierda del paréntesis te quedaría

```
    0000 0000 0000 0010 0010 0000 0000 0000
```

Xor con el mismo sin desplazarse:

```
     0000 0000 0000 0010 0010 0000 0000 0000
 ^  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     0000 0000 0000 0010 0010 0000 0001 0001
```